# MATLAB inline function error

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run this simple MATLAB routine. which will plot a window function.

```
M = 26;
n = [0:(M-1)];
om = linspace(-pi, pi, 201); % for displaying frequency response  
oc = pi/6; % cutoff frequency
% desired impulse response:
hd = inline('1*(abs(om) < oc)', 'om', 'oc');
stem(n, hd, 'filled')
axis([0 M-1 -0.1, 0.3]), xlabel 'n', ylabel 'h[n]'
```

But i am getting the following error

> ??? Error using ==> inline.subsref at 14
>   Not enough inputs to inline function.
>
> Error in ==> xychk at 80
>   if isvectorY,       y = y(:); end
>
> Error in ==> stem at 43
>   [msg,x,y] = xychk(args{1:nargs},'plot');

i feel inline function has enough inputs . but error says no. 
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT # 1

so i learned how to use anonymous function and hopefully used it correctly but now i am having another little error.  Here is the edited code.

```
 M = 26;
n = [0:(M-1)];
om = linspace(-pi, pi, 201); % for displaying frequency response  
oc = pi/6; % cutoff frequency
% desired impulse response:
hd = @(om,oc) 1*abs(om) < oc;
hn = hd(om,oc);
stem(n, hn, 'filled')
axis([0 M-1 -0.1, 0.3]), xlabel 'n', ylabel 'h[n]'
```

i get the error X must be same length as Y in stem. I get the point. But i cant understand how to make n and hn of equal length. n is from -pi to + pi i am sure. but isnt hd also from -pi to + pi. Also can you tell how to make it from -pi to pi if it isnt already.

Comment: Straight from the help for `inline` in R2013a: "`inline` will be removed in a future release. Use anonymous functions instead." Inline functions have been pretty much defunct for several years now. You really should [learn how to use anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), which are more powerful and faster.

Comment: @horchler.... i have now used anonymous function. But i am having another problem. I have added edit 1 about that problem. I am sorry i ma not proficient in matlab so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @horchler... also i have came across fir1 in the meantime.. but i cant figure out if i can use it for a rectangular window or is fir1 only for humming window.

Comment: Either let `om = linspace(-pi, pi, M);` or change to `M = 201;` so that `n` and `om` will have the same length. My guess it that you'll actually eat to plot `om(hn)` as `hn` is just Booleans. No idea about `fir1` – that sounds like the subject of a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that `stem` doesn't know the value of `oc` and `om` when it tries to get y-values from your inline function.

In general, it is preferable to use anonymous functions instead of inlines (also since inlines will be obsolete in the future):

```
hd = @(x,y) 1*abs(x)<y;

stem(n,hd(om,oc),'filled') %# this is also how you should call stem if you use the inline
```

The `@(...)` part defines how many inputs the function takes; the part after than states the function of the two inputs. Note that you can have additional variables appearing in the function definition. Their values are fixed at the time the anonymous function is defined.

The output is a function like e.g. `sin`, and can be called as such.

Comment: Either way - I think the issue is that there were no arguments passed to `hd` in the `stem` line where it had zero inputs as opposed to the 2 it requires.

Comment: @Dan: yes, `stem` doesn't know what value `oc` and `om` have. I forgot to add this to my answer.

Comment: but i want ot use inline. what am i doing wrong in that code... i still dont get it  :/

Comment: @Jonas.. yes i have now used anonymous function. but i am having another problem (added in edit).. can u help with that. i am not very good a matlab.

Comment: also i have came across fir1 in the meantime.. but i cant figure out if i can use it for a rectangular window or is fir1 only for humming window. –

Comment: @user128806: you need to make sure that `n` and `hn` have the same number of elements. See @horchler's comment for the solution. Also, ask a different question for the filters, maybe on dsp.stackexchange.com